# mongoimport error when importing JSON from BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator output

Tags: json, mongodb, google-bigquery, airflow, mongoimport

Summary: I am trying to improve our daily transfer of data from BigQuery into a MongoDB Cluster using Airflow - getting `mongoimport` error at the end.

We need to transfer 5 - 15GB of data daily from BigQuery to MongoDB. This transfer is not brand new data, it replaces data from the previous day that is outdated (our DB size mostly stays the same, does not grow 15GB per day). Our Airflow DAG used to use a `PythonOperator` to transfer data from BigQuery into MongoDB, which relied on a Python function that did everything (connect to BQ, connect to Mongo, query data into pandas, insert into Mongo, create Mongo indexes). It looked something like the function in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078173/optimizing-airflow-task-that-transfers-data-from-bigquery-into-mongodb).

This task took the name of a BigQuery table as a parameter, and using python it creates a table with the same name in our MongoDB Cluster. However it is slow. `as_dataframe()` is slow, and `insert_many()` is slow-ish as well. When this task is run for many big tables at once, we also receive out-of-memory errors. To handle this, we've created a separate `transfer_full_table_chunked` function that also transfers from BigQuery to Mongo, but uses a for-loop, querying/inserting small chunks at a time. This prevents the out of memory errors, but it results in 100 queries + inserts per table, which seems like a lot for 1 table transfer.

Per an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393836/scheduling-load-from-bigquery-to-mongodb-using-apache-airflow-cloud-composer) with a few upvotes:

> I would recommend writing data from BigQuery to a durable storage service like Cloud Storage then loading into MongoDB from there.

Following the suggestion, we've created this task:

```
transfer_this_table_to_gcs = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='transfer_this_table_to_gcs',
    source_project_dataset_table='myproject.mydataset.mytable',
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=['gs://my-bucket/this-table/conference-*.json'],
    export_format='JSON',
    bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_conn_id'
)
```

...which does successfully export our BigQuery table into GCS, automatically creating multiple files using the partition key we've set in BigQuery for the table. Here's a snippet of one of those files (this is newline delimited JSON I think):

[image]

**However**, when we try to run `mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://user@cluster-cluster.dwxnd.gcp.mongodb.net/mydb" --collection new_mongo_collection --drop --file path/to/conference-00000000000.json`

we get the error:

```
2020-11-13T11:53:02.709-0800    connected to: localhost
2020-11-13T11:53:02.866-0800    dropping: mydb.new_mongo_collection
2020-11-13T11:53:03.024-0800    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '_' looking for beginning of value
2020-11-13T11:53:03.025-0800    imported 0 documents
```

I see that the very first thing in the file is a `_id`, which is probably the invalid character that the error message is referring to. This `_id` is explicitly in there for MongoDB as the unique identifier for the row. I'm not quite sure what to do about this / if this is an issue with the data format (ndjson), or with our table specifically.

How can I transfer large data daily from BigQuery to MongoDB in general?

Comment: But aint that a csv file. use `--type csv`

Comment: let me know if you get an error

Comment: yeah it is a `csv` - it seems like the `Operator` is not responding correctly to the `export_format = JSON`. When I manually used the BigQuery UI to export to GCS, and then ran `mongoimport`, that import was actually successful!

I'm going to replace the Operator with the examples from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data and I think this is going to work.

Comment: Alright, won't paste an answer, if you want you can do it :-) but you can always [gift me a coffee](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/minsky)